# Resize and overlay SVG image over jpg in HTML

Tags: html, svg, jpeg

I have an online book I'd like to PDF. Each page has a jpg background and SVG text.

I thought the easiest way to rescale and overlay the SVG over the jpg is via HTML.

However, I cannot get the SVG to overlay (and resize) over the background jpg.

I have opened the SVG and deleted the hard-coded dimensions.

```
<div id='book-page' style='position:relative; overflow:none; display:inline-block; border: 1px black solid;'>
    <img src='page0022.jpg' />
    <svg id="0022.svg">
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not make the jpg the background image of the div?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have to admit i'm a little out of my depth here. I'd like to overlay the SVG so it has the same size as the other image.

Comment: Look at how to set a background image in css, and how to size the SVG. The div that wraps around the SVG, absent any sizing parameters of its own, will adopt the same size as the SVG it wraps